# Выбор инструментов для создания кроссплатформенного проекта на C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide

Приветствую.

Есть проект под *Visual Studio*. Может потребоваться перенести этот проект на *MacOS* и *Ubuntu*.

Вопрос: какие мне нужно выбрать инструменты (IDE, компиляторы и так далее) под *Windows*, чтобы я потом без проблем смог перенести его на другие платформы?

Могу ли я остаться на *Visual Studio* и не огрести потом проблем с переносом?

Есть ли какая то "особая" связка инструментов, благодаря которым я смогу с минимальными изменениями просто откомпилировать проект под все платформы и всё?

Благодарю.

*p.s. Только учусь. Не бейте.*

Comment: Кроссплатформенных IDE навалом, но основная проблема не в них, а в коде :)

Comment: @PinkTux ну некоторые вещи конечно придётся переписать, но я вроде платформо-независимые штуки юзал.

Comment: Ну, про мак не скажу, но по опыту - код сначала пишется и отлаживается под Linux, а в Windows только доводится по-мелочи. Так получается меньше возни, чем наоборот: windows-код приспосабливать под Linux. IDE - Eclipse CDT в обоих случаях, но если есть требование чтобы Windows-версия собиралась в студии, то без неё всё равно никуда. Правда, в ней уже сборка проверяется в самую последнюю очередь :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Emacs**. Отличная штука оказывается. Сначала плевался, но поддался на уговоры знакомых. Целую неделю настраивал, зато теперь нарадоваться не могу.